# Visual Basic System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.' It worked before but now it doesn't. What happen?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, error-handling

So, my code was working before, I never touched it since, I come back cause now I need it and for some reason it wont work. I also got an old back up to compare what was wrong, and the old back up didn't have a problem but the finalized version does. Here's the code, I made two forms:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Dim Chars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub




    Private Sub Employee_DataBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'Save
        'Me.Validate()
        'Me.Employee_DataBindingSource.EndEdit()
        'Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.EmployeeDatabaseDataSet)
        btnSave.PerformClick()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'EmployeeDatabaseDataSet1.Employee_Data' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Employee_DataTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.EmployeeDatabaseDataSet1.Employee_Data)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'EmployeeDatabaseDataSet.Employee_Data' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        'Me.Employee_DataTableAdapter.Fill(Me.EmployeeDatabaseDataSet.Employee_Data)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Application.Exit() 'Exits the application upon pressing the btnCancel

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        'Adds new profile
        ' MsgBox("You pressed Add New Profile")
        Try
            With btnAdd
                If .Text = "Add New Profile" Then 'If the literal text of the button is equal to that, then we shall continue with the execution
                    Employee_DataBindingSource1.AddNew() 'Adds a new profile to the Access Database as it is the source
                    .Text = "Cancel"            'Changes the Text of the Button to show Cancel
                Else
                    RefreshData()

                    .Text = "Add New Profile"
                End If

            End With
            With txtLuxFirstName
                If (.CanSelect) Then
                    .Text = String.Empty
                    .Select()
                End If
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception 'If there is an error/exception
            MsgBox("An Error Occured: " & ex.Message.ToString(), 'A message will pop up saying "An Error Occured : (Actual Error Identification)"
                MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add new profile failed.") 'And will continue displaying the error information



        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim par As String
        par = "^([0-9a-zA-z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$"


        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLuxFirstName.Text) Or IsNumeric(txtLuxFirstName.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLuxLastName.Text) Or IsNumeric(txtLuxLastName.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text) Or Regex.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text, par) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMobile.Text) Or txtMobile.Text = Chars Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtIncome.Text) Or txtIncome.Text = Chars Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct variables for the respective fields")
        Else
            Try
                Dim result As DialogResult
                result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the selected profile?", "Save Profile",
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
                If (result = DialogResult.Yes) Then
                    Validate()
                    Employee_DataBindingSource1.EndEdit()
                    TableAdapterManager1.UpdateAll(Me.EmployeeDatabaseDataSet1)
                    MessageBox.Show("The Profile has been saved successfully.",
                            "Save Profile", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)



                    RefreshData()
                    btnAdd.Text = "Add New Profile"

                Else

                    Return
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Save Profile Failed: " & ex.Message.ToString(),
                                "Save Profile", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)



            End Try
        End If









    End Sub


    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Try
            If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to permanently delete the selected record?",
                               "Delete Data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) Then
                Employee_DataBindingSource1.RemoveCurrent()
                Employee_DataBindingSource1.EndEdit()
                Employee_DataTableAdapter1.Update(EmployeeDatabaseDataSet1.Employee_Data)

                RefreshData()
                MessageBox.Show("The Profile has been deleted successfully.",
                                "Delete Profile", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)




            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Delete Data Failed: " & ex.Message.ToString(),
                            "Delete Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub RefreshData()
        Try
            Me.Employee_DataBindingSource1.Filter = Nothing
            Me.Employee_DataTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.EmployeeDatabaseDataSet1.Employee_Data)




        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Refresh Data Error")

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnJob_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnJob.Click
        Form2.Show()

    End Sub






End Class
```

When I run the code, the:

```
Me.Employee_DataTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.EmployeeDatabaseDataSet1.Employee_Data)
```

line of code gets an error which is in the question. This literally worked before Idk what happened.
And yes I connected it to the Access Database.

Comment: Check Employee_DataTableAdapter in your Dataset designer.  Look at the Fill command.  Has that changed?  e.g. a parameter added.

Comment: I do not believe the Fill command has changed if I am looking at the correct one. it says under Employee_DataTableAdapter in the Dataset Designer: Fill,GetData (). This is on for both the finalized version of the code and the old back up. So nothing has changed I think.

Comment: Was it because I added a query in the Access Database?

Comment: The usual reason for this error is that there may be misspellings or non-existent column names and missing corresponding values in your query. Please check your query carefully.